# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got1)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to convert an image into a numpy array and when I do, it gives me the error that is mentioned in my title. 
The traceback error comes from the line:

```
nx,ny = np.shape(matrix)
```

The rest of my code is below. Could I have some suggestions to fix this?

```
#change the quoted part to change directory and
#file type
filelist = glob.glob('Desktop/*.png')

#set Matrix as the numpy array.
#change the second half were np
#is used to make the program 
#use a different set of data

matrix = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist])


#numpy array
nx,ny = np.shape(matrix)
CXY = np.zeros([ny, nx])
for i in range(ny):
    for j in range(nx):
        CXY[i,j] = np.max(matrix[j,i,:])

#Binary data
np.save('/home/l/Desktop/maximums.npy', CXY)
#Human readable data
np.savetxt('/home/l/Desktop/maximums.txt', CXY)
```

Comment: One suggestion is to include your FULL traceback so we know where you're getting the error.

Comment: `nx,ny = np.shape(matrix)`  if the matrix has only one dimension, this will be your error source.

Comment: Can you include error traceback?

Comment: @DanielF is correct. I guess you're creating an array of dimension 1 with `np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist])` as the list comprehension will produce a list of `Image` objects, this is not correct. More details needed to understand what is `Image` and why you use a list comprehension for loading your data.

Comment: This is called unpacking. When you have an iterable (list, tuple, or anything that supports indexing), a syntax like x, y = point gets the point[0], point[1] elements and assigns them to x, y respectively. However, if there is no point[0] or point[1] it will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

When you construct an array like this, make sure you understand what you get.  In particular verify the shape and dtype.

```
matrix = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist])

nx,ny = np.shape(matrix)
```

Unpacking like this works only if `matrix` is 2d, that is, its shape is 2 element tuple, one element for each of the 2 variables.

This indexing, `matrix[j,i,:]` suggests you expect `matrix` to be 3d.  That would produce an unpacking error, `expected 2, got 3`.

```
CXY = np.zeros([ny, nx])
for i in range(ny):
    for j in range(nx):
        CXY[i,j] = np.max(matrix[j,i,:])
```

But the actual error tells us that `matrix` is 1d.  I suspect it is also `object` dtype.  THat is, a 1d array of arrays.

I'm guessing a bit about what's going on in the `matrix` creation.  `Image.open(fname)` - what does this do?  Open a file? read it as well?  Why the `np.array()` wrapper.  But lets assume it loads a 2d or 3d image array.  Are all images the same size?  If they differ, the outer `np.array` can't assemble them into a higher dimensional array.  Instead it resorts to making a 1d object array - an array of arrays.

In sum, make sure you understand how `matrix` is constructed, and what it produces.

`nx, ny = ...` can be handy, but it is unforgiving.  If the dimensions are wrong it raises an error without much information.